# Waiting for an InputStream from Jclouds (Java)

Tags: java, asynchronous, inputstream, openstack, jclouds

I have a java program that is retrieving an InputStream from OpenStack Swift Object Storage using the Jclouds API.

I am having an issue reading the contents of this InputStream, the contents generally return null when I run the program without any Thread.sleeps or debugging. When I do add a "Thread.sleep(2000);" before each line read, the file reads just fine. Additionally when I step through the reading process in debug mode the read occurs fine.

I am attempting to read the contents of the InputStream line by line, and this is the distilled code for retrieving and reading the InputStream:

```
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.SwiftApi;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.domain.SwiftObject;
import org.jclouds.openstack.swift.v1.features.ObjectApi;

ObjectApi api = this.container.getObjectApi();
SwiftObject obj = api.get(this.file);
InputStream file = obj.getPayload.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file));
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(INITIAL_READ_SIZE);
for(int c = reader.read(); c> -1 && c !='\n'; c = reader.read()) {
    sb.append((char) c);
}
return sb.length > 0 ? Optional.of(sb) : Optional.empty();
```

When I run this code without debugging or without sleeping the Thread this returns nothing. So I am convinced it is a timing issue, since waiting causes the read to succeed. My confusion is that I was under the impression that Read for BufferedReader is blocking, as documented here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--

When I try to see the .available on the inputStream immediately after creation it reads as 0. I know that a Thread.sleep will partially solve the problem, but i'm hoping to find a more sensible solution.

If anyone has any experience with this sort of issue I would be very grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Never use InputStream.available(), as it is not reliable for all types and subclasses of InputStream

Comment: [`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) provides a [`readLine()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine--) method. Out of curiosity - why aren't you using that?

Comment: The actual reading part is done by opencsv.CSVReader, this is just a distillation of what that CSV reader is doing with the InputStream. I have a local copy of openCSV and i've tried to change the actual read method, but with no luck.

Comment: What does "contents generally return null" mean; which call specifically?  Swift is an eventually consistent system so that doing a put immediately followed by a get might fail.